# Order By Meta_key but convert custom date to Y-m-d first

Tags: user-meta

So I have a meta key called sermon_date. Without having to change the custom post type format for Y-m-d and then editing all of the sermons to have that date....they are in m-d-Y format currently.

So here is my query:

```
$wp_query=new WP_Query(array (
        'post_type' => 'sermon',
        'meta_key' => 'sermon_date',
        'orderby' => array('meta_value' => 'DESC'),
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
    );
```

How can I convert the sermon_date to Y-m-d format before it considers the orderby?

Answer (score 2):

I actually found a cool value for the orderby option in this case.

meta_value_datetime

It works the same as using strtotime and the date methods in PHP. So here is my final code that started working:

```
$wp_query=new WP_Query(array (
        'post_type' => 'sermon',
        'meta_key' => 'sermon_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_datetime',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
    );
```